# socket.io RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceede

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

i got this error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at /var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:124:28
    at Array. (/var/www/test.com/io/server.js:106:9)
    at run (/var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:124:11)
    at /var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:132:7
    at Array. (/var/www/test.com/io/server.js:106:9)
    at run (/var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:124:11)
    at /var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:132:7
    at Array. (/var/www/test.com/io/server.js:106:9)
    at run (/var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:124:11)
    at /var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:132:7
    at Array. (/var/www/test.com/io/server.js:106:9)
    at run (/var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:124:11)
    at /var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:132:7
    at Array. (/var/www/test.com/io/server.js:106:9)
    at run (/var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:124:11)
    at /var/www/test.com/io/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:132:7
```

Code Lines 103 - 107:

```
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    server.use((socket, next) => {
        socket.handshake.address = socket.handshake.headers['x-real-ip'];
        next(); //Line 106
    });
```

It runs 5 days without any problems... but now i got this error once and the server stopped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not put `.use()` inside a `connection` event handler.  That will cause them to build-up over time.  Instead, you put `.use()` at the top level.  It works just like the Express model where `.use()` is middleware that is run BEFORE you process the connection in the connection event.  So, it should be like this:

```
// middleware to set the ip address
server.use((socket, next) => {
    socket.handshake.address = socket.handshake.headers['x-real-ip'];
    next(); //Line 106
});

// handle new incoming connections
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // whatever else you want here
});
```